# fail to get data from an updated HtmlTable object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webserver

i am a starter at asp and while trying to do some table dynamic updates i got stuck with a strange issue:
first on page load i take some data from xml file and add it to my table. this part did not cause any problem and the data is shown on the page.
the second part is when i try to write the table's updated data back to the file, there i get back an empty file. after looking at the values in the debug mode it seems that when i get the HtmlTable instance and check the Row attribute there is only one row which is the header row.

attaching the table declaration:

```
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" runat="server">     
<thead> 
<tr class="ui-widget-header ">          
<th>Title</th>                       
<th>Link From Ibms</th> 
<th>Dismiss</th>    
</tr> 
</thead>   
</table>
```

and the reading and writing function on the server:

```
 private void readLinkXml()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))                                                          //   no file.
            return;

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
        reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
    //    reader.Read();

        while (!reader.EOF)                                                              //  load loop
        {

            if ((reader.Name == "ChannelMap" && !reader.IsStartElement()))
            {
                break;
            }

            while ((reader.Name != "links" || !reader.IsStartElement()))
                reader.Read();                                                          // advance to next <links> tag

            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

            HtmlTableCell title = new HtmlTableCell();
            title.InnerHtml = reader.GetAttribute("TITLE");                             // get link title.
            row.Cells.Add(title);
            HtmlTableCell link = new HtmlTableCell();
            link.InnerHtml = reader.GetAttribute("VOD_URL");                            // get link url.
            row.Cells.Add(link);
            HtmlTableCell buttonCell = new HtmlTableCell();
            buttonCell.Attributes.Add("id", "table_button");
            row.Cells.Add(buttonCell);

            users.Rows.Add(row);                                                        //  add xml asset as row in link table.                         
            reader.Read();                                                              // and now either at <links> tag or </ChannelMap
        }


        reader.Close();
    }


    private void writeLinksXml()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "  ";
        settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
        settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings);

        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("ChannelMap");

        bool first = true;

        foreach (HtmlTableRow row in users.Rows)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
                continue;
            }

            writer.WriteStartElement("links");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("TITLE", row.Cells[0].InnerText);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("VOD_URL", row.Cells[1].InnerText);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

does anyone knows why i am not able to retrieve the data i just added to the table?

thanks,
moshe

Comment: nobody knows what may be the problem here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It seems with the issue as all called Why view-state is required in aspnet.
From your question I guess that you have bind Data in `Page_Load()` and you may also have used

```
Page.IsPostBack
```

which is good thing to do.

Now when you do post back you need to make sure that you are binding the same control ( It doesn't matter what it is GridView,DataList anything...).

So Bind Again after each Postback or put your data in ViewState if you want to reduce calls with the XML File.

Comment: i'm sorry but i am new to asp so maybe you can be more spisific on how to bind the control (in my case the dynamic table)?

Comment: As I mentioned in my last reply, From your code what i understand is you are binding or generating HTML table dynamically at Page_Load()

No doubt the Page_Load() calls each time but since you are updating the XML file you need to again call the same method which generates the HTML dynamically making sure that the html you generated last time was not there on the page. Otherwise it would duplicate some of the results in the list.

Comment: ok so when i do load the xml on every post the xml result will be received.  the problem is that the xml saves only my former data , so after loading the data to the table the first time the user is able to change the table content dynamically via javascript.  is there no way to get that extra data which is added dynamically?

Comment: Well in such case when user changes the data in the table you need to update the same in your XML file at the server as well.

Since you are using javascript to update the data what you can try is Asynchronous calls to the server( I mean AJAX). 

I have been using jQuery to do so by $.ajax({}); get details about how to at www.jQuery.com

Comment: thanks Hiren! i didn't try ajax before and the work have to be done as soon as possible so i used the solution from here:  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=203  , but i will try it ajax way next week.  one question: in the ajax approach, can't i loose some of my data between the asychronous calls?

Comment: Well,It's hadn't ever happened with me.Yes few design principal you need to follow when you are doing ajax calls.

Say you want to make an entry in DB. so in such case if user clicks two time on button then it will make two entries in DB. So in such case when user makes click you do you JS data processing and when data is sent to server you can disable the button or you can show some process notification. The best example come into my mind is when you send message in facebook, They follow the same process as well.

Comment: Hi,  just wanted to say i tried the ajax way and it's working very well.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `readLinkXml()` happens in the `Page_Init` of your page.
Otherwise, when the viewstate tries to update the rows when you PostBack - it doesn't find the data and can't change the values.

Comment: doesn't the Page_Init is called only once when the page is requested for the first time only?

Comment: Nope, page_init is called everytime, before the page_load and before the viewstate is parsed